# Log4j 2 custom appender

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I am upgrading log4j 1 to log4j 2. I have a custom appender created in log4j1 and in append(LoggingEvent event) method I retrieve error stack trace using event.getThrowableStrRep() and append '\t' for each line.

I don't see getThrowableStrRep in log4j2. Could you please help me out how we can do this in log4j2?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to custom your own throwable message, you need create your own plugin, which should extend `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.LogEventPatternConverter` and override the `format` method.

- Learn how to custom plugin with
  http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#PatternConverters.
- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/ThrowablePatternConverter.html is a example to convert LogEvent to throwable message.

After you create your own plugin, refer to http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout for using it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the sourcecode of [LogEventAdapter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/xref/org/apache/log4j/bridge/LogEventAdapter.html), it converts the stacktrace as follows:

```
return Throwables.toStringList(event.getThrown()).toArray(Strings.EMPTY_ARRAY);
```